# Swift dictionary, una key con múltiples valores

Tags: swift, xcode, diccionarios

Me gustaría saber como puedo hacer que una clave de un diccionario tenga múltiples valores según los datos que le vayan llegando.

Adjunto ejemplo básico:

```
var tempMD = [String: String] ()

tempMD ["Comedor"] = "Mesa"
tempMD ["Comedor"] = "Silla"
```

En este caso siempre me devuelve "Silla", el último que añado, y necesito que se me retornen todos los items que vaya añadiendo sobre la misma clave.

En este caso debería de tener la clave "Comedor" dos items que son "Mesa" y "Silla".

Gracias por vuestra ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes declarar un diccionario cuyo *value* sea un *array* y este puede contener los datos que quieras, por ejemplo:

```
var temp = [String: [String]]()

temp["Hola"] = ["Hi", "Hello", "Hey"]
temp["Adios"] = ["Bye", "Good Bye"]
```

En este caso `temp["Hola"]` tendrá `["Hi", "Hello", "Hey"]`

Mientras que `temp["Hola"]![0]` tendrá `Hi`

Si quieres agregar un nuevo elemento lo puedes hacer de esta forma:

```
temp["Hola"]!.append("Howdy")
```

Ahora `temp["Hola"]` tendrá `["Hi", "Hello", "Hey", "Howdy"]`

Comment: Mil gracias lo he implementado y todo me va perfecto.

Answer (score 2):

Tendrías que redeclarar tu Dictionario para que sea del tipo `[String: [String]]` y modificar el código para que este de la siguiente manera:

```
var tempMD = [String: [String]]()
```

Y para agregar objetos sería de la siguiente manera:

```
    if tempMD["Comedor"] != nil {
        tempMD["Comedor"]!.append("Mesa")
    } else {
        tempMD["Comedor"] = ["Silla"]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Así es como funciona el [diccionario](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) :

> En informática, una matriz asociativa, mapa, tabla de símbolos o diccionario es un tipo abstracto de datos compuesto por una colección de pares (clave, valor), de modo que cada clave posible aparece a lo sumo una vez en la colección.

Asi que

```
var tempMD = [String: String] ()
tempMD["Comedor"] = "Mesa"
tempMD["Comedor"] = "Silla"
print(tempMD)
```

Imprimirá solamente la parte "Comedor" - ​​"Silla".

**Para esto puede necesitar una matriz de tuplas en su lugar:**

Puede ser: `var tempMD = [String: [String]]()` o  `var tempMD = [(String, String)]()`  que es equivalente a `Dictionary<String, Array<String>>`

```
var tempMD = [(String, String)]() 
tempMD.append(("Comedor", "Mesa"))
tempMD.append(("Comedor", "Silla"))
print(tempMD)
```

Esto si imprimirá ambos pares.

Answer (score -1):

Primero tienes tu diccionario inicializado solo para recibir `String`, en este caso tu necesitas un `Array` por lo que mejor seria utilizar el tipo `Any` como dice en la documentación de apple:

> **Any** puede representar una instancia de cualquier tipo, incluidos los tipos de funciones.

Tu código quedaría así:

```
var tempMD = [String: Any] ()

tempMD["Comedor"] = ["mesa", "silla"]
```

aqui puedes ver mas informacion: [TypeCasting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID338)